# Create SharePoint 2010 list datasource using Microsoft flow

Tags: 2010, microsoft-flow, datasource

Is it possible to create a data source from SharePoint 2010 list using Microsoft flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As a short answer:** Yes, It's possible.

**Microsoft Flow** is a public cloud service only. However, you can securely connect to your own on-premises services through the `on-premises data gateway`.

**The supported data sources are:**

- SQL Server
- SharePoint
- Oracle
- Informix
- Filesystem
- DB2

To configure on-premises data gateway for SharePoint check [Understand on-premises data gateways for Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/gateway-reference/)

Comment: Thank you are you sure it will work for SP 2010?

Comment: you are welcome, as I have mentioned above and In link you can securely connect to your own on-premises services like SharePoint data source, to be honest, I don't try it for 2010 because I didn't have environment 2010 right now!